# openReplay to show the whole input not only first three characters

Tags: session-replay

Is it possible to show in openReplay sessions in the input fields not only the first three characters?
Even if I set the following settings in the tracker constructor, I still see only the first three characters, and after the fourth they all become asterisks.

```
    obscureTextEmails: false,
    obscureTextNumbers: false,
    obscureInputEmails: false,
    defaultInputMode: 0 // plain, not obscured nor ignored
```

If I don't set this settings, then what's entered into input field become asterisk from the first character on. So these settings do take effect.

I'm just wondering, if it's even possible, or if that's just how it is and works as intended ...

Comment: What is the version you are using? it worked for us on 11.7 over angular app integration

Answer (score 0):

We have just did the same thing, setting these configurations fixed it for us:

```
obscureTextEmails: false,
obscureTextNumbers: false,
obscureInputEmails: false,
defaultInputMode: 0
```

One thing you need to consider, if the input is in iframe this might not work.